# how to print a char from struct

Tags: c, sockets

Could someone please tell us to print a char when receiving data as a struct? Here is an example:

```
...
struct rcv{
  int x1;
  float x2;
  char *x3;
}; 
rcv data_rcv;
...
if (recv(socket, &data_rcv, sizeof(data_rcv), 0) < 0)
printf("recv() failed");
...

printf("x1 = %d\n", data_rcv.x1);
printf("x2 = %f\n", data_rcv.x2); 

printf("x3 = %s\n", data_rcv.x3); // it doesn't print anything, why? 
...
```

Let's suppose that x3 is string transfered through a socket, as such:

```
...
char *str1="data-of-app.1"

struct snd{
  int x1;
  float x2;
  char *x3;
}; 
snd data_snd;
...
data_snd.snd = str1;
...
if (send(socket, &data_snd, sizeof(data_snd), 0) < 0)
printf("send() failed");
...
```

Thanks for your replies-

Comment: You shouldn't send a pointer through a socket because that is rarely going to work. Instead, you should declare `x3` as an array of type `char`.

Comment: @dreamlax ... Thanks! now i understood where is the problem . You are right ! we can't send a pointer through a socket ... thanks again for remark!

Answer (score 6):

```
printf("x3 = %s\n", data_rcv.x3);
```

should be

```
printf("x3 = %c\n", data_rcv.x3);
```

Comment: The answer posted by caf is better.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, `x3` is not a `char` - it's a pointer to `char`.  In most cases, pointer values are only meaningful in the process that they originally belonged to.  If you send a pointer value to another process through a socket, the receiving process can't usually make any use of it.

What you probably want to do instead is to send an array of `char` (or possibly just a single `char`, it's hard to tell from your question) - so your `struct` should look like:

```
struct rcv {
  int x1;
  float x2;
  char x3[LENGTH];
};
```

or maybe:

```
struct rcv {
  int x1;
  float x2;
  char x3;
};
```

(If you use the second form, you will need to use `%c` instead of `%s` in the `printf` format string).

As an additional thought, you should bear in mind that if you are sending to a process that isn't compiled with the same compiler and targetting the same architecture, the size and layout of the `struct` itself, as well as that of the individual members, is unlikely to match up and you will recieve garbage.

---

In answer to your question in comments:

You should use the same `struct` definition on both the sending and recieving sides.  If you have a struct like this:

```
#define N 100

struct rcv {
    int x1;
    float x2;
    char x3[N];
};
```

...and you want to put a string into the `x3` member, just use `strcpy` (or better, `strncat`):

```
struct rcv data;

data.x3[0] = 0;
strncat(data.x3, some_string, N - 1);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. the problem is not about the compiler, as i am using the same and the same compiler ...but it is how to send char through sockets when dealing with struct() ... thanks again

Comment: Sure, that was just extra information that I was throwing there at the end.  The main point is that your `struct` doesn't contain a `char` at all - it contains a `char *`, which is (usually) meaningless to send between processes.  To fix your problem, you need to change that `char *` member to either `char [N]` or a `char`.

Comment: @Caf ... thanks! a lot for your suggestions. you are right! we can 't send a pointer through a socket . Just another question plz ... how can we assign char of struct to another as such e.g., #define N=100 ... struct snd {char x3[N];}; snd data_snd;  ... struct rcv {char x3[N];};rcv data_rcv; ... data_rcv.x3=data_snd.x3; //this is not working ... i tried even strcpy(), it doesn't compile ... thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of `struct snd` and `struct rcv`, you should use the same structure definition on both sides.  See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`%s` tries to print a null-terminated string, and expects the parameter to be a `char` pointer. Instead it is getting a `char` value (and since a pointer on all modern machines is larger than a `char`, it's also getting some garbage after it), which is *very bad*.

Instead, you should use `%c`.

Comment: thanks for reply. even when using %c, it doesn't print the whole string ... it displays only one character... so is there any othe way? thanks!

Comment: If you're sending a string rather than a single character as your edit suggests, follow caf's answer.

Comment: shawabkeh .. thanks! yes , you are right ... sorry i forgot to put * when I posted a question ... thanks again for the reply!